# How I can write the JavaScript code for Chrome extension that scroll down till end (I want to get all Facebook friends list)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, infinite-scroll

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I have to read all my friends on Facebook without API.
I have used window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); in while loop with sleep function in Javascript but sleep pause all the javascript execution and Facebook data not load well.

friend list link
https://web.facebook.com/profile-id/friends_all

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You need to post a code snippet. This allows responders to see what you've tried, judge your level of sophistication (allowing answers tailored to your skill level), and provide a relevant reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it this way- scroll, wait for the more content to load, compare scroll heights, and repeat if more content was loaded. Here's the implementation with async/await and setTimeout sleep duration:

```js
(async (sleepDuration = 2000) => {
  let previousHeight;
  let newHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
  do {
    previousHeight = newHeight;
    window.scrollTo(0, previousHeight);
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, sleepDuration));
    newHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
  } while (previousHeight !== newHeight);
})();
```